# How to name file and directory the same with .htaccess rewrite rules?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to work on my "pretty-urls" and I'll be the first to admit I really don't know what I'm doing. I'm trying to wrap my head around it though. So what I am trying to do is have a file.php, but then also have a directory called file. That way I can go to www.example.com/file and it should pull up file.php. But I also want to be able to go to www.example.com/file/subfile and it should go to subfile.php IN the file directory.

Right now, I'm able to get rid of ".php" on all files and I've figured out how to "hide" the $_GET parameters in the URL, but this directory/file issue is throwing me for a loop. Any help is appreciated!

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^dire1/file/([0-9]+) dir1/file.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^dir2/example/([0-9]+) dir2/example.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is problem when you enter `www.example.com/file` in browser?

Comment: It takes me to the directory, not the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `mod-dir` Apache directory module that runs before `mod-rewrite` . When you request an existent directory without a traling slash the `mod-dir` issues a permanent 301 Redirect from `/dir` to `/dir/` and that is why you are unable to rewrite the uri.

To fix this, you need to tell mod-dir not to perform the redirection  when a directory without a traling slash is requested. You can use `DirectorySlash` directive in your htaccess to change this behaviour.

Add the following line to your htaccess :

```
DirectorySlash off
```

Reference :
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^dire1/file/([0-9]+) dir1/file.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^dir2/example/([0-9]+) dir2/example.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Last rule will serve `/file.php` when URI is `example.com/file/`

Note that if you serve `example.com/file` (no trailing slash) then Apache's `mod_dir` module will add a trailing slash in the end to make it `example.com/file/` and then server `/file.php`.

Turning off this trailing slash behavior is considered a security risk and it may expose your internal directory structure to your visitors.